# Redirect with Javascript on Contact form with send.php

Tags: javascript, php, contact-form

I'm recreating my site and I've included a contact form for users to contact me when needed. I found a javascript that redirects with a countdown timer.

contact.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Contact Form</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" /> 
<meta name="description" content="" /> 
<link href="tooplate_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script  src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="tooplate_wrapper">

    <div id="tooplate_header">

        <div id="site_title"><h1><a href="http://deathsrepo.pw">Technologx</a></h1></div>         
        <div id="twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/Technologx" target="_blank"></a></div>

        <div id="facebook"><a href="https://facebook.com/Technologx2013" target="_blank"></a></div>

        <div id="tooplate_menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://deathsrepo.pw/themes.php">Themes</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://blog.deathsrepo.pw">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://deathsrepo.pw/store.php">Store</a></li>
                <li class="last"></li>
                <li><a href="http://deathsrepo.pw/contact_form.php" class="current">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li class="last"></li>
            </ul>       
        </div> <!-- end of tooplate_menu -->
<style>


body, div, h1,h2, form, fieldset, input, textarea, footer,p {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: none;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'YanoneKaffeesatzRegular';
    src: url('fonts/yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.svg#YanoneKaffeesatzRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body { font-family: 'YanoneKaffeesatzRegular';}
p {text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff; font-size:24px;}
#wrap {width:530px; margin:20px auto 0; height:1000px;}
h1 {margin-bottom:20px; text-align:center;font-size:48px; text-shadow:0 1px 0 #ede8d9; }


    #form_wrap { overflow:hidden; height:446px; position:relative; top:0px;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;
        -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;
        transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;}

    #form_wrap:before {content:"";
        position:absolute;
        bottom:128px;left:0px;
        background:url('images/before.png');
        width:530px;height: 316px;}

    #form_wrap:after {content:"";position:absolute;
        bottom:0px;left:0;
        background:url('images/after.png');
        width:530px;height: 260px; }

    #form_wrap.hide:after, #form_wrap.hide:before {display:none; }
    #form_wrap:hover {height:776px;top:-200px;}


    form {background:#f7f2ec url('images/letter_bg.png'); 
        position:relative;top:200px;overflow:hidden;
        height:200px;width:400px;margin:0px auto;padding:20px; 
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 3px; 
        -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #9d9d9d, inset 0px 0px 27px #fff;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #9d9d9d, inset 0px 0px 14px #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #9d9d9d, inset 0px 0px 27px #fff;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;
        -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;
        transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;}


        #form_wrap:hover form {height:530px;}

        label {
            margin: 11px 20px 0 0; 
            font-size: 16px; color: #b3aba1;
            text-transform: uppercase; 
            text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
        }

        input[type=text], textarea {
            font: 14px normal normal uppercase helvetica, arial, serif;
            color: #7c7873;background:none;
            width: 380px; height: 36px; padding: 0px 10px; margin: 0 0 10px 0;
            border:1px solid #f8f5f1;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px #726959;
            -webkit-box-shadow:  inset 0px 0px 1px #b3a895; 
            box-shadow:  inset 0px 0px 1px #b3a895;
        }   

        textarea { height: 80px; padding-top:14px;}

        textarea:focus, input[type=text]:focus {background:rgba(255,255,255,.35);}

        #form_wrap input[type=submit] {
            position:relative;font-family: 'YanoneKaffeesatzRegular'; 
            font-size:24px; color: #7c7873;text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
            width:100%; text-align:center;opacity:0;
            background:none;
            cursor: pointer;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; 
            -webkit-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out 0s;
            -moz-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out 0s;
            -o-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out 0s;
            transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out 0s;
        }

        #form_wrap:hover input[type=submit] {z-index:1;opacity:1;
            -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out 1.3s;
            -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out 1.3s;
            -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out 1.3s;
            transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out 1.3s;}

            #form_wrap:hover input:hover[type=submit] {color:#435c70;}

</style>
<body><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div id="wrap">
        <h1>Contact Form</h1>
        <div id='form_wrap'>
            <form method="post" action="php/send.php">
                <p>Hello Guest,</p>
                <label for="email">Your Message : </label>
                <textarea  name="message" value="Your Message" id="message" ></textarea>    
                <label for="name">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" />
                <label for="email">Email: </label>
                <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" />
                <input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Send" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the send.php:

```
<style>

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #9c9893;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.7em; 
    background-color: #111212;
    background-image: url(../images/tooplate_body.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: top center
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 5;
    var redirect = "http://test.deathsrepo.pw";

    function countDown(){
        var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
        if(count > 0){
            count--;
            timer.innerHTML = "This page will redirect in "+count+" seconds.";
            setTimeout("countDown()", 1000);
        }else{
            window.location.href = redirect;
        }
    }
    </script>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "deathsarepo@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = "Help Needed";
    $subject2 = "Help Needed!";
    $message = $name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Thank you your submission was sent" . $name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }
?>
```

The email function works but the redirection script isn't working it just stays there at the send.php. Giving the users the back button option on the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $to = "deathsarepo@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = "Help Needed";
    $subject2 = "Help Needed!";
    $message = $name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Thank you your submission was sent" . $name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
}
```

with:

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $to = "deathsarepo@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = "Help Needed";
    $subject2 = "Help Needed!";
    $message = $name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Thank you your submission was sent" . $name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.

    //new lines
    echo '<div id="timer"></div>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">countDown()</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I only took a quick look but I didn't see anything that ever fired your countdown timer to start. Your solution might be as simple as :

```
   countDown();
}
</script>
```

Comment: It would safe also to put this javascript in the bottom of the page when everything else (especially <div id="timer">) is loaded.

Comment: @mlewis54 the fire code is this setTimeout("countDown()", 1000);

Comment: The countdown timer is to redirect the user back to the home page after they submit their question. The extra CSS is for the menu buttons, etc...